# Removing the "with Google Friend Connect" text from following widget

Tags: html, css, widget, blogs, blogger

I'm having trouble removing the "with Google Friend Connect" text from the followers widget in blogger. I used chrome's devtool and found this,

```html
<div class="gfc-footer-msg" jstcache="0">with Google Friend Connect</div>
```

I copied that code and just removed the "with Google Friend Connect" and added that VIA css LOL... but it didn't work. Don't know what to do from here :/ #noobcoderhere

Comment: Perhaps you didn't save or your didn't upload your code to your blog. You did it correctly. Removing 'with google friend connect' will remove that text from your blog.

Comment: Please give feedback for any answers for your question.

Answer (score 0):

just add this css code to your template editor exactly before `</b:skin>` closing tag.

```
.gfc-footer-msg {
    display: none!important;
}
```